# Migrating disposition data from one SFMC instance to SFMC another one

Tags: marketing-cloud

I don't think it is possible but I just wanted to confirm. Is it possible to ask SF customer support to migrate disposition data from previous Salesforce marketing cloud to another one?

Comment: What is "disposition data"?

Comment: they are  the hard bounce/soft bounce, unsub, open click.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to migrate all your tracking data from your previous account to native tracking data in your new account.

It is possible to take this data and import to Data Extensions in your new account where it can be used for segmentation or summarisation. This would not be a Support case, however. Rather, you would either need to do this yourself using tracking extracts or data views, have a Partner do this for you or engage SFMC's own services to carry out the work.